# How to estimate gas for subsequent contract interaction in the same call

Tags: gas-estimate

I have the same issue as here:
[Can I estimate the total gas limit of several dependent transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77863/can-i-estimate-the-total-gas-limit-of-several-dependent-transactions)

But i need to know the result on the fly in my react application.

Anyone has an idea?